# Capture Changes to Parent Visual Tree

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, visual-tree

**From within a WPF [`FrameworkElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), how can I capture any changes to the visual tree path from the root to the `FrameworkElement`?** i.e. when the `FrameworkElement`, or any of its parents, is added to, removed from, or moved to another branch of a visual tree?

- I have been looking for appropriate events, but while `FrameworkElement` has an [`OnVisualParentChanged` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.onvisualparentchanged(v=vs.110).aspx), it does not offer an according event that handlers could be registered for without subclassing the framework element. Hence, this cannot be applied to arbitrary, already instantiated `FrameworkElement`s.
- In theory, A [`RelativeSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) binding should help me here, but for that to work, I already need to know which parent node (what type, what level) I am looking for, which is not the case (see below).

**Use case:** For [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694563/how-to-reuse-existing-layouting-code-for-new-panel-class), one promising possible solution would involve using the current [`NameScope`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.namescope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) relevant for a `FrameworkElement`. The appropriate `NameScope` instance can be retrieved from the [`NameScope` attached property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms601183%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but it is not set for every node in the tree, only for roots of visual trees constructed from [control templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Therefore, to find the appropriate `NameScope` for my `FrameworkElement`, I need to walk up the visual tree until I find a node that has a non-`null` value set for the `NameScope` attached property, and I will have to redo this to possible update the `NameScope` every time anything in the visual tree above my `FrameworkElement` has changed.

[This discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/730b74b6-759e-4295-81b9-8141dd0927dc/visual-tree-updates) touches upon the topic, but it is already 6 years old and doesn't have a solution.